# Ajax Call inside click event is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax call work in a click event but it is giving me an error:

> $.ajax is not a function

My call:

```
module.exports.doaction = (Identifier) => {
    $(Identifier).modal('show');
    $(`${Identifier} a`).click((event) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/action',
            data: event.target.id
        });
    });
};
```

What I am missing?

On my main page the script has been included:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: on console of the browser, the error is coming Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Comment: Can you try $.post instead of ajax?

Comment: What `$` refers to? It probably should refer to jQuery, but does it really?

Comment: yups but same error is coming $.post is not a function.

Comment: $ is by default jquery I guess because if I remove the ajax call the code is working fine, no error.

Comment: Don't guess, log it, then you'll know.

Comment: How did you include jquery in your application?

Comment: `console.log($)` shows what?

Comment: console.log($) shows -  ƒ (a,b){return new r.fn.init(a,b)}

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your application?

Comment: yes on my main page the script has been included : <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>

Comment: It looks that `$` really refers to jQuery.

Comment: yups but still I don't know why it is giving the error.

Comment: Have you tried calling "jQuery.ajax" instead of "$.ajax"?

Comment: Yes, the error is still there

Comment: You have use a build tool to make js app (module.exports.doaction webpack???) run on browser, you link a js lib in your html by `script` tag instead of  require $ in your source code, out side of click event callback function `$` charactor refer to `jQuery`, but `$` binding in click callback function is not refer to `jQuery` because when build tool make `build`, it unknow `what dose $ mean?`.

Try to require jQuery lib in your source code and remove `script` tag. Keyword `jQuery npm`.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is not a function means you didn't included jquery properly.

slim build of jquery doesn't include `ajax` function.

you can include jquery from

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @Teemu, updated

Comment: When I do require('jQuery'), the error is changed to - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: @Akki, updated,I think the problem was jquery type, you have to use not slim type but use full type.